# Linux Beep command not working (not reporting error) on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I'm trying to make `beep` command work on my PC with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS but it's not making a sound.

It's not a laptop but a computer with a case/chassis that was bought quite a few years back by my family, so I guess it's likely to own the necessary hardware (I'm not 100% sure about this and I remember using this PC to play stuff back when I was little so there should at least be a sound card). I'm **not** considering playing a beep audio for substitution for some reasons and I'll just turn to buzzers if this can by no means work.

I've googled and tried many of the suggestions, including editing /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and commenting out the blacklist pcspkr line, but none of them worked. The following is what I get when I try beep, beep --debug and other inputs that are supposed to trigger beeps. I get no error nor sound.

```
xxc@xxc-pc:~/Desktop$ echo -e \\a

xxc@xxc-pc:~/Desktop$ tput bel
xxc@xxc-pc:~/Desktop$ echo -e "\a"

xxc@xxc-pc:~/Desktop$ echo -e "\007"

xxc@xxc-pc:~/Desktop$ printf "\a"
xxc@xxc-pc:~/Desktop$ beep
xxc@xxc-pc:~/Desktop$ beep --debug
beep: Verbose: beep_drivers_register 0x5579854ed600 (console)
beep: Verbose: beep_drivers_register 0x5579854ed660 (evdev)
beep: Verbose: evdev driver_detect 0x5579854ed660 (nil)
beep: Verbose: b-lib: opened /dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr as 3
beep: Verbose: beep: using driver 0x5579854ed660 (name=evdev, fd=3, dev=/dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr)
beep: Verbose: 1 times 200 ms beeps (100 ms delay between, 0 ms delay after) @ 440 Hz
beep: Verbose: evdev driver_begin_tone 0x5579854ed660 440
beep: Verbose: evdev driver_end_tone 0x5579854ed660
beep: Verbose: evdev driver_end_tone 0x5579854ed660
beep: Verbose: evdev driver_fini 0x5579854ed660
```

It seems that `beep` is able to find the driver, so it confuses me why it's not working. I don't have a spare speaker at the moment, so I just plugged a headphone (and I of course tried without the headphone) on to the case as I learnt from https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PC_speaker this may also work. I'm relatively new to hardwares and English is not my first language, so please excuse me for any inconvenience and confusion. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: um, this might be random selection, but the last 4 or 5 mainboards I bought (over the last decade), none hat a buzzer anymore on board. I'm not sure if my current mainboard still has that. Do you maybe need to connect a speaker to a speaker header on-board, like in the old OLD old days (1970–ca 2000)?

Comment: @Marcus Müller I’m actually suspecting the same but I'm supposing that the shell will report some kind of error if that's the case (like can't find device)... Is there a way to check this without having to open up my case? (It's really just some random brand and it's hard to recall the model/type)

Comment: no, it wouldn't. The computer can't know whether there's a speaker attached.

Comment: You've probably seen this already, but there are several possible answers provided at https://askubuntu.com/questions/19906/beep-in-shell-script-not-working.

Comment: @David Yockey Thank you but yes, I've checked this already.

Comment: @Marcus Müller I see... So will attaching a separate ordinary speaker do the job or do I have to use speakers attached to the board?